# Owl Carousel not working with different classes

Tags: jquery, owl-carousel-2

So i am making a site, and i need more sliders on it, with different classes so I can customize them, for example on slider will display 3 slides, another one will display only one.

Here is the code for one of them:

```
<div class="testimonials owl-carousel owl-theme owl-loaded">
  <div class="owl-stage-outer">
    <div class="owl-stage">
      <div class="owl-item">
        <div class="s__t__card">
          Distinctively myocardinate adaptive action items without high-quality initiatives. Holisticly envisioneer web-enabled methodologies with integrated relationships. Energistically engage covalent action items whereas customer directed technology. Interactively customize stand-alone services via reliable results.a
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
loop: true,
margin: 30,  
nav: false,
dots: false,
autoplay: true,
autoplaySpeed: 2000,
autoplayTimeout: 4000,
responsive: {
  1000: {
    items: 3,
  }
}});
  $('.testimonials').owlCarousel({
loop: true,
margin: 30,  
nav: false,
dots: true,
autoplay: true,
autoplaySpeed: 2000,
autoplayTimeout: 4000,
responsive: {
  1000: {
    items: 1,
  }
}});});
```

[Here is what it does](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqKe1.png)

It shows 3 slides instead of 1, please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

basically the problem was that i tried to change the carousel settings in `$('.owl-carousel).owlCarousel({})`, but i had to do it in the second class of the carousel, for example the first carousel i did had the class 'features', so i changed my first `$('.owl-carousel).owlCarousel({})` to `$('.features').owlCarousel({})`

Answer (score 0):

`$('.owl-carousel')` will initiate the sliders with the same parameters because you have the class in both carousels

Change `$('.owl-carousel')` to `$('.owl-carousel:not(".testimonials")')` or remove the `owl-carousel` class from the second carousels

Comment: i added ':not(".testimonials")' to '$('owl-carousel')', but only the function 'items' works, 'nav', 'dots' and others don't work at all for '.testimonials'

Answer (score 0):

Since You Have "testimonials" And "owl-carousel" Classes in Same Div Owl Plugin Initiates Both At Same Time.

Either You Can Maintain Two Separate Div's For Both Carousel Initialization Or Initiate Either One Of The Carousel  With $('.owl-carousel:not(".testimonials")').owlCarousel({}); Or $('.testimonials:not(".owl-carousel")').owlCarousel({});

Comment: i added ':not(".testimonials")' to '$('owl-carousel')', but only the function 'items' works, 'nav', 'dots' and others don't work at all for '.testimonials'